# How to change Data type of a column in Mongo collection using Spring Boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a pojo class Student for which i made a collection students

```
@Document(collection="students")
@Data
@Builder
class Student{

@Id
private String id;
private String major;
private int phNo;
private Date dob;
}
```

I had to change the dob to type `long dob` to convert it to epoch but after that all the repo operations stopped working. I am assuming we have to change the type in db too when we change the datatype in collection.

I had changed the name of the field too I used one of the suggested approach using **mongoTemplate**

```
    BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    BasicDBObject updateQuery = new BasicDBObject();
    updateQuery.append("$rename",new BasicDBObject().append("field1", "field11"));  
 mongoTemplate.getCollection("students").updateMany(searchQuery,updateQuery);
         }
```

how do i do this for changing the field type using **mongoTemplate**.

Answer (score 0):

The **@JsonProperty** annotation is used to map property names with JSON keys during serialization and deserialization. By default, if you try to serialize a POJO, the generated JSON will have keys mapped to the fields of the POJO. If you want to override this behavior, you can use the @JsonProperty annotation on the fields. It takes a String attribute that specifies the name that should be mapped to the field during serialization.

Try using this and create a POJO class Student like this :

```
@Document(collection="students")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
class Student{

    @JsonPropertyOrder({
            "id",
            "major",
            "phNo",
            "dob"
    })

    @Id
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty("major")
    private String major;

    @JsonProperty("phNo")
    private int phNo;

    @JsonProperty("dob")
    private long dob;
}
```